# How to SHUTDOWN Tomcat in Ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I tried to shutdown **tomcat** as shown below, but tomcat still seems to be running (http://localhost:8080/)

> ```
> vandegraff@vandegraff-laptop:~$ /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/shutdown.sh 
> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat6
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat6
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat6/temp
> Using JRE_HOME:       /usr
> 1 Nov, 2010 11:41:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
> SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
> at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
> at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:422)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:337)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
> ```

**Why is that?**

---

Update1 for @hvgotcodes:

Output of **ps -ax | grep java**

> 1597 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/jsvc -user tomcat6 -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -outfile SYSLOG -errfile SYSLOG -pidfile /var/run/tomcat6.pid -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-temp -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/var/lib/tomcat6/work/catalina.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
>
> 1598 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/jsvc -user tomcat6 -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -outfile SYSLOG -errfile SYSLOG -pidfile /var/run/tomcat6.pid -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-temp -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/var/lib/tomcat6/work/catalina.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
>
> 1599 ?        Sl     0:20 /usr/bin/jsvc -user tomcat6 -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -outfile SYSLOG -errfile SYSLOG -pidfile /var/run/tomcat6.pid -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-temp -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/var/lib/tomcat6/work/catalina.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Should all these 3 processes - **1597, 1598, 1599** - be killed?

Comment: did you try with superuser privileges?

Comment: Most likely, your Tomcat is not running and shutdown.sh can't connect to its management interface to shut it down.

Comment: Is there another application/service listening on port 8080?

Comment: killing one will probably kill them all, but you can just do 'sudo kill -9 1597, 1598, 1599'

Comment: I dont understand why we need sudo, I started it use my own user. and people didn't explain why the shutdown.sh script didn't work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Van, in your case where tomcat won't shutdown normally, i  would use

```
ps ax | grep java
```

to find the java process number.  If that command returns something, then run

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

where pid is the process number.  The -9 option means 'just kill it', and normally you don't need this sort of thing, but since in your situation the process won't stop normally, you need it.

The output of the first command should look like

```
38678 s002  U      0:02.62 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/conf/logging.properties -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxxx -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.26 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.26 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

38678 is the process number.  Be aware that there might be other java processes running that you might not want to kill. Also, this output is from a mac, so on ubuntu will look slightly different.

Comment: Isn't `kill -9` a little bit too aggressive?

Comment: @thejh, ive been following his threads -- he needs to just kill it in this case.

Comment: I think `killall` would suit better in this case, using `ps ax | awk '/java/ && /tomcat/ && !/awk/ {print $1}'` would give only the tomcat related processes with nothing more, you can give this output to `killall` and save most of the hassle.

Answer (score 55):

Try

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat stop
```

(maybe you have to write something after `tomcat`, just press tab one time)

Edit: And you also need to do it as root.

Comment: this one worked for me. /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/shutdown.sh threw an exception saying "SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/server.xml (No such file or directory)"

Comment: In the case that this didn't work for some people you have to put tomcat and the version you have installed for instance I had tomcat 7 installed so i had to put /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop

Answer (score 27):

Try using this command : (this will stop tomcat servlet this really helps)

> sudo service tomcat7 stop

or

> sudo tomcat7 restart (if you need a restart)

Comment: `sudo service tomcat7 restart` (if you need a restart)

Comment: Using Ubuntu, and got the exact same error as OP. This answer was correct. I am using `tomcat9`

Answer (score 4):

For a more graceful way, try the following:

**Caveat: I'm running Debian 7, not Ubuntu, though it is a Debian derivative**

If you're running Tomcat as a service, you can get a list of all running services by typing:

**sudo service --status-all**

I'm running Tomcat 7, which is displayed as *tomcat7* in said list. Then, to shut it down just type:

**sudo service tomcat7 stop**

Answer (score 3):

To stop apache process try this command

ps aux | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to use `killall`?

Comment: This will just kill the pid of `grep`. Just run `ps aux | grep tomcat` several times to see...

Answer (score 3):

If you installed `tomcat` manually, run the `shutdown.sh(/.../tomcat/bin)` from the terminal to **shut it down** easily.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and found the following command to work:

*sudo systemctl stop tomcat*

After running this command you can type the following to verify that it is "disabled":

*systemctl list-units*

[image: output for systemctl list-units]

Answer (score 2):

for tomcat 9, Use following commands

For stop

```
sudo systemctl stop tomcat.service
```

For Start

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat.service
```

For reload tomcat java opts

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: on ubuntu 20.04 i have to use the service `tomcat9`.

You can check the existence of a *tomcat*-service via

- `systemctl list-units` or

- search for a service-file under `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`

Comment: This works for me: sudo systemctl stop tomcat.service Even when rest one are not working for stop tomcat

Answer (score 1):

When running Tomcat under jsvc, it will not respond to the shutdown signal on the specified shutdown port which is sent from the shutdown.sh script. The only way that I'm aware of is to kill the process, however you'll need to kill the ones listed as jsvc, not java.

Answer (score 1):

if you are run this command

```
 debian@debian:~$  /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh
 then your server will not stop and you will get o/p like that you provided if you use in 
 super user mode then effect will appear o/p will come like this

 debian@debian:~$ sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh
 [sudo] password for debian: 
 Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat
 Using CATALINA_HOME:   /var/lib/tomcat
 Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/tomcat/temp
 Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
 Using CLASSPATH:   /var/lib/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/lib/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Comment: didn't work for me at all, and don't make sense as well, as I started with my own userid.

Answer (score 1):

if you have yout tomcat installed you can do :

```
sh path2tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

Comment: How this is different from this answer on the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32563886/6676466

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the **environment variable** for *Tomcat* is set or not use the following command in the terminal:

```
echo $CATALINA_HOME
```

To Start Tomcat:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

To Stop Tomcat:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
```

To check Tomcat started or stopped:
http://localhost:8080/

SCREENSHOTS:
[image: 1.Terminal]
[image: 2.Tomcat Started]
[image: 3.Tomcat Stopped]

Answer (score -1):

None of the suggested solutions worked for me.

I had run `tomcat restart` before completing the deployment which messed up my web app.

EC2 ran tomcat automatically and tomcat was stuck trying to connect to a database connection which was not configured properly.

I just needed to remove my customized context in server.xml, restart tomcat and add the context back in.

Comment: You seriously were unable to `kill -9` it? I find this improbable.

Comment: killed but it was auto-launched again.

Answer (score -1):

Caveat: I'm running Ubuntu

```
sudo service --status-all
```

you can get a list of all running services by typing this command,

If you're running Tomcat as a service it will showes up as ("tomcat"),
so run :

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
```

(tomcat7 or 8 or depending to the name that you have in the list of running services  )

else and if you are using apache tomcat you will see ("apache2") showing up with the list of services then run :

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```